# cannot be cast to (Java swing ActionListener)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I have made have an error that I can not fix.

**Code:**

```
public class Learn extends HelloActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Hello");
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        HelloActionListener listen = new HelloActionListener();
        JButton b1 = new JButton("TOP");
        b1.addActionListener((ActionListener) listen);
        JButton b2 = new JButton("LEFT");
        JButton b3 = new JButton("RIGHT");
        JButton b4 = new JButton("BOTTOM");
        JButton b5 = new JButton("1");
        JButton b6 = new JButton("2");
        JButton b7 = new JButton("3");
        JButton b8 = new JButton("4");
        buttonsPanel.add(b5);
        buttonsPanel.add(b6);
        buttonsPanel.add(b7);
        buttonsPanel.add(b8);

        frame.add(b1, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(b2, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.add(b3, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        frame.add(b4, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class HelloActionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Hello Folks");
    }
}
```

**Error:**

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
> learn.HelloActionListener cannot be cast to
> java.awt.event.ActionListener     at learn.Learn.main(Learn.java:35)
> ```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Post the complete code, from line 1 to last, of HelloActionListener

Comment: I just formed those two classes into one [mcve] and got no compilation error. Voting to close. Please add an MCVE to the question (soon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The class "Learn" should NOT extend ActionListener. It has nothing to do with being an ActionListener. It is just a class that creates a GUI. It doesn't need to extend anything.
2. There is no need to cast the "HelloActionListener" object to an ActionListener.

Just use:

```
b1.addActionListener( listen );
```

Comment: Thank you! But when i replace this 
    [b1.addActionListener((ActionListener) listen); ]     with 
    [b1.addActionListener( listen );]     shows me this error (incompatible types:HekkoActionListener cannot be converted to ActionListener

Comment: @Sakel4, Works fine for me. Maybe you have an old class file lying around. Or maybe you didn't import the ActionListener class.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I have an old class files and that makes me the problem

Answer (score 0):

Adding the listener directly to the button will be somewhat easier.

```
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

        System.out.println("Hello Folks");
     } 

 });
```

Comment: You can upvote any answer you find useful by clicking on the arrows on the left of the answer ...

Comment: Thanks for your time!